# Removing the white space at the bottom of blog

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm new to the programming world.... I'm having trouble removing the white space at the bottom of my blog. I've tried researching everywhere and trying different things but nothing seems to work. Here's my blog, http://goneintranslation.blogspot.ca/. If you scroll down to the bottom of the blog there's this white gap, does anyone know how to get rid of that white gap/ reduce it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Never met anyone who got frustrated over not being able to save an image. @misterManSam

Comment: hmmm, great articles. I guess I'll remove it, since it's redundant...this is all new to me if you're wondering why I'm so naive. @misterManSam

Comment: Sorry if I came across a bit brash - just trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.region-inner.main-inner {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

And get rid of the `<footer></footer>`, as there's nothing in it.

Comment: You'll just want to remove the space, ex.: .region-inner.main-inner

Comment: And in case you're not familiar with where to put the CSS: go to your blog's page, click "Layout" on the left, then click "Template Designer".  Now click "Advanced", then "Add CSS".  Paste the code in and away you go.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it in to the "add CSS" but it didn't work unfortunately. But thanks !

Comment: @FionaChan - try placing it at the bottom of your existing stylesheet. The winning value when equal properties conflict, is often the value that is declared last. You could also try `div.region-inner.main-inner `

Comment: @FionaChan - [Here is a really in-depth explanation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/) on CSS "specificity"

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of think, I like to open up Chrome's DevTools and click on the little magnifying glass icon (it'll say something along the lines of clicking on an element to inspect it, when you roll over the icon).

Then, just move your mouse on top of the area. You'll notice that there is a `div` with the classes `region-inner` and `footer-inner` You can add a CSS rule such as: `div.region-inner.footer-inner { display:none; }` and it will be hidden. (This is assuming you don't have access to the HTML, in which case you could just delete that code)

Using this same technique, you will then see that there is a `div` with the classes `region-inner` and `main-inner` that has a `padding-bottom` property set to 65px. This is creating even more white space at the bottom. Create a CSS rule to adjust that `padding-bottom` to be whatever you'd like it to be.

Comment: hmmm interesting ! I never knew about Chrome's DevTool, I'm new to programming, like very nice (since yesterday). Thank for the help, I'll try to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to find these kind of spaces, I use the developer tools of Chrome. Hovering over the source code can display the boxes covered by the stylesheet. You can collapse the divs and other tags.

This showed me the following:

.footer-inner adds a total padding of 30px (15 top, 15 bottom)
.main-inner gives you padding-bottom: 65px.

Hope this helps.

Stretsh